# Javascript drawing fractals on canvas, issue with recursive save and restore

Tags: javascript, canvas, save, restore

I am trying to draw about 8 transformations on a canvas and I was using the example from ["Sierpniski triangle"](https://klevas.mif.vu.lt/~rimask/wp-content/uploads/canvas/canvas_Sierpinski.html) to draw my own, but I seem to be struggling whenever I increase the step size to be bigger than 1. Here is a fiddle I've got going: [Current code](http://js.do/code/199125)

If you uncomment lines 43 to 49 you would see how it gets broken, but if you decrease the step size in line 14 to be: 1. Then you get a perfect visualization on how it should look like. So the problem is that I've tried multiple methods to save the canvas and restore it, but the fact that I am drawing recursively makes things break.

Another thing, if you uncomment lines 43 to 49 along with line 40 and leave the step size: 2. You get almost a perfect visualization of how it should look like, but the fact that there is an additional flipped shape near every transformation makes it not "perfect".

I have tried HTML5 litten forum, W3S schools and searched along here, but could not find anything similar to it.

Comment: Would be good to include your code directly in the question. Now, I don't have a computer at hand right now to be able to help you more, but don't use save/restore for transformations. Instead re/set to absolute values using setTransform method. You'll find it's far easier to manage. A rule of thumb: if no clip-path, no save, and if clip-path, double check compositing can't do it better.

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't that make fractal drawing way too hard at this point if we discard of using save and restore?

Comment: So I finally got my hands on a computer but haven't too much time to refactor this... Because, I don't think that you are going to reach your  expected result using the [original code you linked to](https://klevas.mif.vu.lt/~rimask/wp-content/uploads/canvas/canvas_Sierpinski.html) as a base. This code only draws in the final steps, i.e, it only draws the small black triangles, the *pseudo-fractal shapes* are actually holes in the drawing.

Comment: Well the specified code is certainly a base which is used to reach the expected result, this is a task originally provided by a lecturer. The shape was refactored to match a different illustration [Link here](https://klevas.mif.vu.lt/~rimask/old/fractals/54.png) . It should not be an exact representation, but drawn similar in terms of shape/boundaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue with the following code:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script type="application/javascript">
 function draw(val=1) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  if (canvas.getContext) {
   var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   drawT(); //Trait around the canvas (black border)
   drawF(val); //draw Fractal
  }
  function drawF(step,color=null)
  {
   var toDraw=false; //Color management variable to separate 4 transformations
   if (step > 0)
   {
    if(color) { toDraw=true; }
    step = step-1;
    ctx.save();
        
    ctx.transform(0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 250,0);
    ctx.rotate(90*Math.PI/180);
    if(toDraw) { ctx.fillStyle=color; }
    else { ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000"; color="#FF0000"; }
 
    drawF(step, color);
    ctx.restore();

    ctx.save();
    ctx.transform(0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 250, 0);
    ctx.scale(-1, 1);
    ctx.rotate(90*Math.PI/180);
    if(toDraw) { ctx.fillStyle=color; }
    else { ctx.fillStyle="#00FF00"; color="#00FF00"; }

    drawF(step, color);
    ctx.restore();
        
    ctx.save();
    ctx.transform(0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 250, 250);
if(toDraw) { ctx.fillStyle=color; }
else { ctx.fillStyle="#0000FF"; color="#0000FF"; }
    
    drawF(step, color);
    ctx.restore();
    
    ctx.save();
    ctx.transform(0.2, 0, 0, 0.25, 250, 250);
    ctx.scale(1,1);
    ctx.rotate(90*Math.PI/180);
        if(toDraw) { ctx.fillStyle=color; }
        else { ctx.fillStyle="#FFFF00"; color="#FFFF00"; }
        
    drawF(step, color);
    ctx.restore();
   } else {
    drawShape();
   }
  }
  function drawT() {
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
   ctx.lineTo(500,0);
   ctx.lineTo(500,500);
   ctx.lineTo(300,500);
   ctx.lineTo(300,400);
   ctx.lineTo(150,400);
   ctx.lineTo(150,250);
   ctx.lineTo(0, 250);
   ctx.closePath();
   ctx.stroke();
  }

  function drawShape() {
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.moveTo(0,0);
   ctx.lineTo(500,0);
   ctx.lineTo(500,500);
   ctx.lineTo(300,500);
   ctx.lineTo(300,400);
   ctx.lineTo(150,400);
   ctx.lineTo(150,250);
   ctx.lineTo(0, 250);
   ctx.closePath();
   ctx.fill();
  }
 }
 function showVal(newVal){
  draw(newVal);
 }
 </script>
</head>
 <body onload="draw();">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
 </body>
 <input type="range" min="1" max="7" step="1" value="1"
 oninput="showVal(this.value)" onchange="showVal(this.value)">
</html>
```

Use the slider for transformation proccess.